# Orthogonal Group

Tags: group-theory, geometry, algebraic-topology, orthogonal-matrices

(Note: $O(n) = O(n, \Bbb{R})$)

I've notice that $O(1)$ is equivalent to $S^0$. And I've read that $O(2)$ is equivalent to two copies of the circle group $S^1$.

I was wondering if someone can explain why this is?

Also is there a general (similar) rule for O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with “equivalent”. However, $O(1,\mathbb{R})=\{1,-1\}=S^0$. On the other hand$$O(2,\mathbb{R})=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,\theta\in\mathbb R\right\}\cup\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\,\middle|\,\theta\in\mathbb R\right\}$$and this expresses $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ as the union of two disjoint sets, each of which is homeomorphic with $S^1$.

On the other hand, $O(3,\mathbb R)$ is $3$-dimensional, whereas $S^2$ is $2$-dimensional. Therefore, there is no similar relation between $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ and $S^2$.

Comment: Why is $O(2,\Bbb{R})$ as above? I get that one set is the rotations which is $SO(2,\Bbb{R})$, but the other?

Comment: @Niall $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$. So, the matrices of the second set are those of the first one times $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. They are those matrices from $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ whose determinant is $-1$.

Comment: Is there anything we can say about $O(3,\Bbb{R})$? Again, I've read that its the symmetric group of $S^3$? and in general $O(n, \Bbb{R})$ is the symmetric group of the $(n-1)$-sphere $n \neq 3$?

Comment: @Niall It's more complicated than that. The group $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ is a copy of two groups each of which is what we obtain when we identify each point of $S^3$ with its antipode. I am not aware of anything similar with respect to $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ when $n>3$.

Comment: Thanks! I was basing it on wikipedia so it may not be the most reliable!